# mysql2 inserting values nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mysql2, node-mysql2

I have this post request

```
app.post("/msg", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  connection.query('INSERT INTO plans (topic, notes, resources) VALUES 
  (?)', [req.body.topic, req.body.note, req.body.resource],(error, 
  results) => {
     if (error) return res.json({ error: error });

     });
 });
```

and i get this error from  it

```
"error": {
    "code": "ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW",
    "errno": 1136,
    "sqlState": "21S01",
    "sqlMessage": "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"
}
```

this is the table

```
CREATE TABLE plans(
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  topic VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  notes VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  resources VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
 );
```

please whats wrong with the request ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to provide the question mark according to number of column values you are providing.

```
app.post("/msg", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  connection.query('INSERT INTO plans (topic, notes, resources) VALUES 
  (?,?,?)', [req.body.topic, req.body.note, req.body.resource],(error, 
  results) => {
     if (error) return res.json({ error: error });

     });
 });
```

this should work

Comment: Why did you put ?, ?, ? after values and then a comma and then put the req.body after that?

Comment: Because we are trying to insert 3 values in table row.

Comment: Gotcha my bad. I see you made the comment above too. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: Any suggestion on inserting multiple rows?